# How to save image that in EditText to SharedPreferences and read it out?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I write a richText Edit, I want to insert some image into EidtText use these code:

```
    public void insertImage(int i,Context context){

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.notes_icon);
    if(i==1){
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.smileyface);
    }
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(bitmap);
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("face");
    spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    EditText contentText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.content);
    contentText.append(spannableString);
}
```

That it work , the image display in EditText. But I want to save content to SharedPreferences. I use Html.toHtml , I found the img tab is  and save to SharedPreferences. So when I read it out and display to EditText the image became white box.

How to give some value behind imge scr when Html.toHtml? because there are lots of image, I want to recognition from different value.

Comment: Post your solution here, so that others can get benefit of it.